# find maximum no. in matlab

Tags: matlab, find

I have 1901 g values. I am accumulating it in t as

```
xr=[qq] ; %Training and Anomaly Samples in sequence
z=numel(xr);
N=100;
t=zeros(1,z-N+1);
for n5=0:z-N;
x=xr(1+n5:N+n5);
d=max(x);
m1=numel(x);
y=zeros(d,1);
p=zeros(d,d);
    for k=1:m1-1
     y(x(k))=y(x(k))+1;
     p(x(k),x(k+1))=p(x(k),x(k+1))+1;
    end
    p=bsxfun(@rdivide,p,y);
    p(isnan(p))=0;
    b2=sum(log(p(p~=0)));
    [~,~,idx] = unique(x);
    q=prod(hist(idx,1:max(idx))/numel(x));
    l=log(q);
    g1=b2+l;
  t(n5+1)=g1; %log value    
end
```

in above qq generated by other code and has a integers in between 1 to 100, qq length is 2000. here t has length in 1901. when I am doing `max(t)`  then it showing answer.   so how to find  maximum value among first 400 iterations. when I am doing max(t(1:400)) it showing error

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.  so how his error occurs.
```

Comment: Are you sure your indices start from 1 ? I ran the code and it works for me. The only problem could be that some of the indices from 1:60 are missing values

Comment: t(n+1)=g, and n start from 0 so t has values from 1. and  all indices are present.

Comment: Can you update the question with the complete code. I can't workout the problem here as this works fine if n is an integer and all indices are present.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you've created a variable called `max` which is masking the function of the same name.

Do `clear max` and then try again?

Comment: yes, sorry I already have max for entire t and then I am again using max for  selected values so error comes. now it showing ok.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I'm very confused about your `y(x(k))=y(x(k))+1` line. If you go step by step, does your `y` end up like you expect?

Do a `whos t` to make sure the elements of your array are the type you expect them to be, which will affect which brackets you use for your index. I run into this all the time, and I don't think I'll ever get it straight in my head without a cheatsheet.